# create an object with a property name from a parameter

Tags: javascript

How can I create an object with a property which name comes from another variable?

In the example I expected obj to be `{ foo: 123, nacho: 'tama' }` but `me` is not resolved, it is taken literally.

```
var me = "nacho"
var obj = { me: "tama" };
// obj is { me: 'tama' } but I expected { nacho: 'tama' }
```

PS: I know I can it could done in two steps using brackets:

```
var obj = {};
obj[me] = "tama";
```

Is is possible to do this at `obj` creation time?

Comment: `eval()` or perhaps the function constructor. Otherwise: no.

Comment: It's possible in ES6. The duplicate question mentions that.